# AWS Trust Assume Role from Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have quite a few users in an AWS Account - let's call it the Base account:

```
IAM:
  groups:
    admins:
      user1
      user2
      user3
      ....
      user56
```

I have created a second AWS account - let's call it the Dev account with a single Role with AdministratorAccess.

```
IAM:
  Roles:
    AdminRole
```

I tried to add a Trust Relationship between Base/admins and Dev/AdminRole with this Trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::************:group/admins" },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

but got the following error:

`An error occurred: Invalid principal in policy....`

How do I allow users in Base/admins to assume the Dev/AdminRole?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to give access to the entire account from Dev/AdminRole and then restrict access from roles in the base account.

Comment: More details about how to do that would improve this answer a lot.